# Facebook Graph API - Retrieve photo - Unsupported get request

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am testing the Facebook Graph API via their explorer. I managed to get my feed using me/home. However, I want to get some details from uploaded pictures.
As I read on other posts, I have to re-run the query using the object_id in the POST object.

This only works for public images. Whenever I try to do this on a friend's photo, I get:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api", 
    "type": "GraphMethodException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

One of them was a photo of my wife. I checked her privacy setting, as far as I can see, she doesn't block 3rd party API's.
How can I get photo details of posts that the API returns in me/home?

I know that it doesn't work for photo's with unique permissions (so e.g. with tags in them), but I tested it with photo's only shared with that person's friends. Tested about 10, none of them work. How is this possible?

Comment: Has your wife's account authorized your application to have access to her photos? This is the `user_photos` permission.

Comment: I use the Graph API, so I log in as myself. She has granted 3rd party apps access to her photos.

Comment: Her user has to authorize **your** application. You can't grant permission to any 3rd party app - it has to be for a specific application.

Comment: Think of it this way - should *my* application have access to her photos? **Absolutely not** - that would be a serious security violation... Only applications that she has authenticated have access.

Comment: That sounds weird. That would mean that a 3rd party app would only be able to open the user's own photos.
I need access to photos that are posted on the timeline (me/home). So, that's not possible?

Comment: But, the issue is: In the response from me/home I get one post-object about the fact she uploaded 7 photo's. In my app I want to show those 7 photo's, so I would need to open that album. The only way to get to that album is through the photo... Or not?

Comment: Yea - access to the actual album would need permissions. However, according to the documentation, you should be able to see: [`"The feed of posts (including status updates) and links published by this person, or by others on this person's profile."`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/feed).

Comment: Are you sure that the photo is actually posted **to the timeline** and not just appearing there because you are tagged in the post/photo? I too can not see a photo through the API from my timeline that was posted by someone else even though it does appear in my feed. But this photo was not posted to me - I was only tagged in it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62908/discussion-between-boland-and-lix).

Comment: Hi Boland, did you eventually find solution for this? I also met same problem.

Comment: Nope. Never fixed it. I quit developing my app, because of the extremely annoying app submission rules for FB apps, e.g. I cannot request read_stream on an Android app...